# SQL Server count value of column

Tags: sql-server, count

I call the table is [vDemo]
[[image: I call the table is [vDemo]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtiC1.png)

i want count MaLC by TenNV, result is
[image]

if record 13 MaLC is L then Count(x) = 16, Count(L) = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM` or `COUNT` functions to do this, with a `case` expression:

```
select
   TenNV
   ,SUM(count_x) as count_x
   ,SUM(count_L) as count_l
from
(
select 
  TenNV
  ,Case when MaLC = 'x' then 1 else 0 end as count_x
  ,Case when MaLC = 'L' then 1 else 0 end as count_L
from vDemo
) A
group by TenNV
```

or with COUNT:

```
select
   TenNV
   ,COUNT(count_x) as count_x
   ,COUNT(count_L) as count_l
from
(
select 
  TenNV
  ,Case when MaLC = 'x' then MaLC else NULL end as count_x
  ,Case when MaLC = 'L' then MaLC else NULL end as count_L
from vDemo
) A
group by TenNV
```

output of this:

```
TenNV   count_x count_l
Cam     5       0
Ngo     17      0
```

dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=934757424cee361d48990b718b80342e)

Comment: I really appreciate your help with my project! Thanks for supported !

Comment: It's a "CASE expression", not statement.